# ASP.NET MVC Nuget Packages Scripts folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I know I can use bower for this but due to some work restrictions I have been told that my JS dependencies I need to pull from Nuget Package Manager. What I do not want to do is version control the files that are downloaded. So when I delete the files in the Scripts folder and rebuild the solution, there is no new files being loaded? Is this possible, during the build process to check the scripts file and load the JS files? Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. But can't you do this with Visual Studio's pre-build event? Also, your version control might ignore the packages folder -- at least git does this.

Comment: I ended up using xcopy for that. I wonder is that going to work for then I deploy the app to azure?